# How do I create Sales Order on ERPNext using the frappe python client?

Tags: python, erpnext, frappe

I’m using frappe python client to create Sales Order but for some reason its not getting created. I’m using all mandatory fields for Sales Order (and Sales Order Item). Its not giving any error but its not even getting created.

I am able to create Customer, Shipping Address, Contact and even Lead in a similar way but creating Sales Order is not working.

Its returning “None” when I’m trying to print it.
I have attached my code below. Please do let me know if I am missing some fields or anything?

Ignore the values, I’ve changed them before posting here.

```
client = FrappeClient(apiConfig.erpNextUrl)
client.authenticate(apiConfig.erpNextApiKey, apiConfig.erpNextApiSecret)

sales_order = client.insert({
    "doctype": "Sales Order",
    "order_type": "Sales",
    "naming_series": "SAL-ORD-.YYYY.-",
    "conversion_rate": 1.00,
    "customer_name": "TEST",
    "company": "TEST-COMPANY",
    "transaction_date": str(date.today()),
    "currency": "INR",
    "selling_price_list": "state price",
    "price_list_currency": "INR",
    "plc_conversion_rate": 1.00,
    "status": "Completed",
    "set_warehouse": "some warehouse",
    "delivery_date": "24-05-2021",
    "grand_total": "₹ 1,800.00",
    "items": [
        {  # included mandatory fields on ERP
            "item_code": "some item code",
            "item_name": "name of the item",
            "uom": "Kg",
            "description": "item description",
            "conversion_factor": 1,
            "qty": 3,
            "price_list_rate": "₹ 700.00",
            "rate": "₹ 700.00",
            "amount": "₹ 2,100.00",
            "stock_uom_rate": "₹ 700.00",
            "net_rate": "₹ 600.00",
            "net_amount": "₹ 1,800.00",
            "billed_amt": "₹ 2,100.00",
            "valuation_rate": "₹ 500.00",
            "gross_profit": "₹ 600.00",
            "projected_qty": 31,
            "actual_qty": 42,
            "delivered_qty": 3,
            "ordered_qty": 0,
            "work_order_qty": 0,
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: You may search for error logs in the desk. You can install development environment and track error messages. You may also try to "Open Recorder" desk page and track activities.

Comment: I should also try to set currency fields without "₹" sign.